# reverse of a sequence in homological algebra

Tags: homological-algebra

Say I have a sequence $C_1 \rightarrow C_2 \rightarrow C_3 \rightarrow... \rightarrow C_n$

In math terminology, what is the "reverse" of this sequence?

Is it $C_n \leftarrow C_{n-1} \leftarrow ... \leftarrow C_1$?

Comment: Can you give some more context?

Comment: see this paper, page 9: http://www.mrzv.org/publications/dualities-persistence/manuscript/

Comment: I think you are right. The author uses it literally.

Comment: I agree with @EclipseSun, perhaps the author wants to use mainly right facing arrows for some sort of consistency?